# Add New Record Field in Kendo UI not Working in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I searched Over the Google. I didn't get any source for my requirement.
My output is like
[image]

If I click the 1st column linkbutton `eFocus011` or other rows linkbutton means it will go to new web bage, but the toolbar `Add new record` was not working, because I used template for `System Name` columns field. How to get the correct output? 
My code:

```
        var grid= $("#DivGrid").kendoGrid(
        {
            dataSource: DataSource4,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: false,
            reorderable: true,
            resizable: true,
            pageable: true,
            toolbar: [ { text : "Add new record",name: "popup",iconClass: "k-icon k-add"} ],
            editable  : {
                mode : "inline"  
                // template: kendo.template($("#customPopUpTemplate").html())
            },
            navigable: true,
            columns: 
            [  
                {
                    field: "SystemName",
                    title: "System Name",
                    width:"130px",
                    // template: '<a href  >#: SystemName # </a>'
                    template:"<a onclick='NewWindow(this.id)' id=\"#= SystemId #\" href='\\#'>#= SystemName #</a>"
                    // template:'<a href class="list k-Linkbutton" onclick="NewWindow(this.id)"  id="#= SystemId#" >#= SystemName #</a>'
                    // template: '<a href="\\#" onclick="NewWindow(this.id)"  id="#= SystemId#"   >#= SystemName #</a>'
                },
                {
                    field: "SystemIP",
                    title: "System IP",
                    width:"100px"
                },
                {
                    field: "SystemType",
                    title: "Type",
                    width:"80px",
                    editor: function (container, options) {
                        $("<input />")
                            .attr("data-bind", "value:SystemType")
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoDropDownList({
                                dataSource: [ { text: "--Select--" ,value: "0"},{ text: "PC" ,value: "1"},{ text: "LAPTOP" ,value: "2" }],
                                dataTextField: "text",
                                dataValueField: "text"
                        });
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "OSKey",
                    title: "OS Key",
                    width:"200px"
                },
                { 
                    command: ["edit","destroy"], 
                    title: "&nbsp;", 
                    width: "190px" 
                }       
            ]
        }).data("kendoGrid"); 

        $(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function ()
        { 
            var popupWithOption = 
            {
                mode: "popup",
                template: kendo.template($("#customPopUpTemplate").html()) ,
                window: {
                    title: "Add New Record"
                }
            };

            grid.options.editable = popupWithOption ;
            grid.addRow();
            $(".k-window-action")
            {
                //visibility: hidden ;
            }
            grid.options.editable = "inline";
        });
    };
</script>
```

Also I used two types of editing. If I click toolbar, means I used popup Kendo editing edit and Delete means inline editing? 
I think error is in

```
 template:"<a onclick='NewWindow(this.id)' id=\"#= SystemId #\" href='\\#'>#= SystemName #</a>"
```

If I changed this line to:

```
 template:"<a onclick='NewWindow(this.id)' id=\"#= SystemId=0 #\" href='\\#'>#= SystemName #</a>"
```

It will work only toolbar, columns linkbutton is not working.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking good to me

Confirm whether SystemId is present in models, if not then Rectify **"SystemId"** to **"SystemIP"** 
and make a check

```
 template:"<a onclick='NewWindow(this.id)' id=\"#= SystemIP#\" href='\\#'>#= SystemName #</a>"
```

Comment: hi @abbas how to get the drop down value inside the kendo template

Comment: the drop down is there in inside the kendo UI template, if i change the drop down means i need changed value .. how to do?